# Dynamic Site Map

Tags: sitemap, web.sitemap

I may be going the completely wrong direction, so any thoughts would be great.  Am looking for a dynamic php sitemap code for a website that constantly has pages that get updates.  Need to find a way to get the php to pull every page in the folder the script is in, look up each file name, title and meta description and output it to something like:

```
 <li><a href="$filename">$title</a>: $metadescription.
```

It also needs to ignore the includes folder and .ico file.  And it just needs to do an update every time a user opens the page.  Have seed a couple of scripts that are an almost, but not quite.  Also, is there a way that other types of sitemaps could be updated/created at the same time so that everything is done in the background?  Any pointing in the right direction would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: In which langauge are you working?  I guess PHP?